# Google Analytics: How can I traffic and referrals from iPad applications?

Tags: google-analytics, mobile

In Google Analytics, there is extensive information on the mobile device, version and browser version. However, this doesn't seem to go beyond the mobile browser.

I would like to determine which application is responsible for visits to my site. Specifically, I want to know how many visits are coming from zite.

http://www.handsetdetection.com/properties/vendormodel/Apple/iPad/page:4

seems to indicate this information is probably available, where/does Google Analytics expose this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track mobile devices with GA, but not the apps generating the traffic.
If you're thinking along the lines of browser headers it may be possible but not with GA.
For that you'd have to create an independent redirection which stores the browser header in a database, and if you're trying to measure a paid link, you can tell them to use the redirect link instead of the original. Otherwise GA collates the browser headers and doesn't offer much in detail.

Comment: Alternatively you can setup your own measuring system that stores the browser header on page load, but you'll have to filter out visits from the same ip within a reasonable amount of time e.g. if a visit is logged it won't be logged until after 2 minutes of the last activity, or you can use a session ID...